# Downloading Catalina to M1 for Intel Macbook

Tags: mac-appstore, apple-silicon, bootable-disk

I need to download macOS Catalina and make a bootable USB for my macbook pro 2015 which has intel chip.

But have only m1 chip macbooks here, can't download from app store. It says

`Not compatible for this device`

I can't trust any source other than official one. So I can't download from torrent.

Is there any workaround.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is basically the same as the [canonical](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2418/where-is-the-list-of-canonical-questions-stored-for-ask-different) question: [How can I download an older version of OS X/macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos) New answers should be posted at this original question.

Comment: Your question explicitly states *"I can't trust any source other than official one"*. I have read the [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/429829/downloading-catalina-to-m1-for-intel-macbook/429832#429832) by Jean_JD that you have accepted. How do you know the macOS that can be downloaded using the software by two canoes is official?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use MDS : https://twocanoes.com/products/mac/mac-deploy-stick/ to download Catalina, then create an usb install key using this : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372

Note that this key must be created with a GUID partition scheme.

Comment: this method is only for downloading. We can't create a bootable usb of macos catalina or older macOS under an M1 chip. Actually the main problem was internet connection of intel mac. In this scenario I have to move downloaded dmg to an intel chip mac.

Comment: @msalihbindak. Once downloaded the dmg, if you open it, you will find into the directory Applications, the installer. app and the createinstallmedia procedure work fine on M1 under Big Sur.

Answer (score 0):

Download [Big Sur](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683) or Monterey to M1 Mac. Create [USB installer](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372) and install on Intel Mac. Download Catalina to Intel Mac. Create [USB installer](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372) and install on Intel Mac.

I can also refer you to the question [How can I download an older version of OS X/macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos)

Comment: Downloading BigSur takes hours in my internet connection because of its size and I don't want to use bigsur. just catalina is ok. 
Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Not really useful as many Intel Macs do not meet the cutoff to run Big Sur and can only run Catalina

Comment: @user1950278: The OP has 2015 MacBook Pro which can run Big Sur. My answer is based on the question being asked.